# Getting md5sum of a file through Crypto.js

Tags: javascript, linux, md5, fileapi, cryptojs

I am trying to get the md5sum of a tar file to produce the same value when using the md5sum linux command and CryptoJS's MD5 method.

In JavaScript I do (after a file has been put in an HTML form):

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function () {
     text = (reader.result);
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(document.getElementById("firmware_firmware").files[0]);

var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(text);

hash.toString();
```

In Linux I do:

```
md5sum name_of_file.tar
```

Currently these two produce different results. How am I able to get JavaScript to get the contents of the tar file to be MD5ed in the same way that md5sum does on Linux?

For a simple String, md5sum and CryptoJS produce the same value.

Edit: With a file called Fred.txt, with content the content: "Fred", both md5sum and CryptoJS produce the same value: c624decb46fa3d60e824389311b252f6.

On the update.tar file, the md5sum on linux gives me: 1f046eedb7d8279953d233e590830e4f, on CryptoJS it gives me: f0c3730e5a9863cffa0ba3fadd531788

Edit2: Further testing shows that this is actually a problem due to large file size such as 7 MegaBytes

Comment: Can you give examples of the output from both? Is it possible that `readAsBinaryString(.....)` is hashing the filename rather than the file contents?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tested it with a simple txt file with a simple string, in that situation md5sum on linux and CryptoJS produce the same result. I'll edit in the outputs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All strings in JavaScript - even "binary strings" - are actually UTF-16 characters. A "binary string" is one that chooses to use only the first 256 code points. Since the Latin-1 encoding also uses exactly the first 256 code points, you can convert the string to bytes using Latin-1.

```
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the file does not finish loading and the hash gets created before the file upload is 100%. Try moving the hashing into the onloadend event:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function () {
     var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(reader.result);
     hash.toString();
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(document.getElementById("firmware_firmware").files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but it didn't work. I appreciate the effort though. It appears through further testing that the different results are only occurring for file a few megabytes in size. So maybe along the right lines, as this is on my local machine, and being done on the client side, could the upload really be an issue though?

Comment: It might also be due to limit in `php.ini` - `max_post_size` or `max_upload_size` or stuff like that. If the file would get uploaded 100%, the hash would be equal with all libs. (if you are using php)

Answer (score 0):

When you're running your bash, make sure you're not sending a newline to hashing function. If you use `echo`, add `-n` parameter:

```
$ echo -n abc | md5sum
900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72  -
```

vs:

```
$ echo abc | md5sum
0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1  -
```