# Calculate MD5 or SHA of an Image using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, cordova, md5, sha

I have a requirement where I need to calculate hash of an Image and upload it to a webservice. The image is captured using Cordova API and the API returns a URI of that image.

I checked the CryptoJS but it is taking a string as input.

```
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
```

Any way we can calculate hash for the image ?

CryptoJS Lib : [CryptoJS Home Page](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

Any other library is also fine as long as it can be used from Cordova App.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cordova API` you can get a `Base64` encoded image instead of the URI. Which you can easily hash using `CryptoJS`.

When calling `getPicture` API use the `DATA_URL` option to get **Base64** encoded image as the result:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });
```

This will return the base64 encoded image in the `onSuccess` method as the param:

```
function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(imageURI);
}
```

Comment: Yaa I know that but as I am uploading it to Amazon S3 I need URI instead of base64. I am using destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI

Comment: in this case using `FILE_URI` you might need the cordova `FILE` plugin and read the file using the URI and hash it's content.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was thinking. Was searching if any other way. Coz you know the more plugins you use the more headache Cordova creates :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way to generate the MD5 of the image file in HTML:

```js
function onFileChange (e) {
  const readerBuffer = new FileReader()
  readerBuffer.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0])
  readerBuffer.onloadend = function (e) {
    const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(e.target.result))
    const content-md5 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
  }
}
```

1. Need to read the image as binary.
2. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263741/getting-md5sum-of-a-file-through-crypto-js), I got that we need to `convert the string to bytes using Latin-1.`

This result can be used as content-md5 by AWS required.